# Display OpenCV Mat with JavaFX

Tags: java, image, opencv, javafx, mat

I would like to display `Mat` objects from OpenCV directly with JavaFX. I have seen that it is possible to convert a `Mat` object into a `BufferedImage`. But as far as I know you can't display a `BufferedImage` with JavaFX, so another conversion would have to take place.

Is there a way to **directly** convert it into a data structure that is displayable by JavaFX?

Comment: It's probably possible to convert directly to FX, using a `WritableImage`. Either by copying pixels from the `Mat` to the `WritableImage`'s `PixelWriter`, or by implementing a `PixelReader` backed by the `Mat`, and use that for instantiating the `WritableImage` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a direct way to convert a `Mat` object to a JavaFX `Image` object.

```
MatOfByte byteMat = new MatOfByte();
Highgui.imencode(".bmp", mat, byteMat);
return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteMat.toArray()));
```

You can also encode it to .jpg but .bmp is faster.

Comment: Why my OpenCV doesn't come with HighGUI library/class ?

Answer (score 4):

TomTom's answer was very helpful and solved the problem, but Highgui does no longer have any bindings in java.

As of OpenCV 3.0.0, the up-to-date code is more like:

```
MatOfByte byteMat = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", mat, byteMat);
return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteMat.toArray()));
```

Comment: Your answer is the solution for OpenCV version 3. Earlier versions use Highgui.

Comment: Thank you for your precision, I just edited and corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The silly way to do this is to convert the `Mat` to a `BufferedImage`, and then that to an `Image` so that it can be displayed inside an `ImageView`:

```
Mat >> BufferedImage >> Image >> ImageView
```

Assuming you know how to do the 1st conversion, the rest would be something like this:

```
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImage, null);

ImageView imgView = new ImageView();
imgView.setImage(image);
```

I haven't tested the code, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of encoding and decoding to get the byte array you need, you can just declare an array and use the `get` method. This is Scala code, but hopefully it's intelligible:

```
val arr = new Array[Byte](w * h * 3)
mat.get(0, 0, arr)
pw.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance, arr, 0, w * 3)
```

This code declares the array `arr` of type `byte[]` with the size corresponding to an image of `h` by `w` and 3 channels. Then the data is copied from the `mat` object into the array, and passed to the `setPixels` method from the `PixelWriter` object `pw`.